# AutoArchive this item now

Tags: microsoft-outlook, archiving

Is it possible to set up a button that would perform the same action that AutoArchive does but do it **now** and **only** with the item(s) under selection?

I know it's possible to create a button to move anything to a "big Archive" folder, but I don't want that.  I like AutoArchive in that it frees up items from my sight but still *keeps the structure* of folders as I like them.

So I would just want a button that would say: don't look at the age or AA settings--this guy can go to archive right away.  (I'd expect to inherit the Archive file from actual settings, though...)

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> opens the "Move To Folder...". After you select your archive folder, Outlook will remember it - therefore you can quickly move files into your archive - it's not one click, but may suffice.

Or, save the move as a quick step (click quick steps and create a new one) - then you can assign keyboard short cut, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will move it to the desired folder. This way, if you have more than 1 archive you can have different numbers for each archive (well, up to 10).

**Update**

Since re-reading your post and your comments, would an option be categorizing everything, then running a rule based upon the categories. IE, mark categories then run the rules; again, still doesn't hit your original request but since no one else is asking, I thought I would at least suggest work a-rounds.

Comment: Sorry but the "workaround" is about what I said I don't want: I have well over 20 sub-folders in my Inbox, and even if I had only 10 having to think about which one of them to use from which folder kind of beats the purpose, plus would be extremely faulty anyway.

Comment: OK, let me update my answer for you